# What is the general opinion H2K information systems?

Tags: learning, training

My mom has recently signed up for a QA training course with http://www.h2kinfosys.com, and I'm not sure if this center would be respected by the industry. They say that the center will help with job placement, but do people really find an entry level software testing positions (preferably workinng remotely) with a certification, some previous projects, and no CS degree?

I've tried looking at job ads online, but most of them seem to be for higher-level positions. Would any companies ever be interested in a part-time tester?

Comment: In case it helps, I've been in QA (in the US) for many, many years, and have never heard of h2k information systems. That said, people find entry level jobs in all sorts of ways. The best way I have found is through friends, and through domain expertise. I have never found any value in certifications where I work (northeastern US). I do hire part-time testers, but never entry-level remote part-timers.

Comment: They're based in Atlanta, so that might explain why you haven't heard of them. How do entry level people demonstrate their knowledge without certification? Is it normal to do some work pro-bono, or do some kind of SQA internship?